# Image color different from mac and iOS device

Tags: iphone, image, ios5, colors, device

I've read some solutions about this color differences but they haven't worked. I tried taking a screenshot from my iphone and compare it to the simulator image or the image in the prview tool and its the same color, only when I see it on the device it looks different.

I'm using SDK 5.1 on XCode 4.3

How can I fix this ?? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OS X `System Preferences` has a `Displays` section where you can adjust the screen colors (I don't know whether that's safe to apply others than "Profiles for this display")[image]

You can either try to use another profile, calibrate the screen or to google more taking this preferences pane into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, guess I`ll keep looking.

Comment: Sure, please update us if you find something interesting, an interesting article about the ios/mac colors i've read today is http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html